# Why do the two identical sides of this model reflect light differently?

Tags: animation, materials, light, lighting, reflection

I've modeled a alien coin, and I added some animation to it. The result has shown me that one side (The one it flips to) reflects light in a much nicer way way than the other side (The one it starts on). They both use an identical material. Why is this?

This is shown in the gif here:

https://giphy.com/gifs/gKTtS0kNoTOIwq7kxX

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there must be a difference, could you please share your file, at least the important parts? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's your normals. Make sure all objects have their normals on the outside.